# Решение СЛАУ по модулю

Tags: c++

Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста. Каким способом, можно решить СЛАУ, если у тебя ответы даны по модулю. Пытался Гауссом, не правильно считает. Или Надо другим методом?

Вот правильно работающий метод Гаусса:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, j, n, m=0;
    //создаем массив
    cout << "Number of equations: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Number of variables: ";
    cin >> m;
    n = 3;
    m += 1;
//  float matrix[3][4];

    float **matrix = new float *[n];
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
        matrix[i] = new float[m];

    //инициализируем

    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)

        for (j = 0; j<m; j++)
        {
            cout << " Element " << "[" << i + 1 << " , " << j + 1 << "]: ";

            cin >> matrix[i][j];
        }

    //выводим массив
    cout << "matrix: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<m; j++)
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    //Метод Гаусса
    //Прямой ход, приведение к верхнетреугольному виду
    float  tmp;
    int k;
    float *xx = new float[m];

    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        tmp = matrix[i][i];
        for (j = n; j >= i; j--)
            matrix[i][j] /= tmp;
        for (j = i + 1; j<n; j++)
        {
            tmp = matrix[j][i];
            for (k = n; k >= i; k--)
                matrix[j][k] -= tmp*matrix[i][k];
        }
    }
    /*обратный ход*/
    xx[n - 1] = matrix[n - 1][n];
    for (i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        xx[i] = matrix[i][n];
        for (j = i + 1; j<n; j++) xx[i] -= matrix[i][j] * xx[j];
    }

    //Выводим решения
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
        cout << xx[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    delete[] matrix;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Правильно работает при

```
    101 47
    120 53
    030 54
```

Должны получиться ответы: 30 18 17. А как сделать, чтобы он так же правильно решал, когда ответы даны по модулю? Например по модулю 46:

```
101 1
120 7
030 8
```

Comment: Да конечно покажите. Как Вы хотите чтобы Вам помогли? Тут нету телепатов =)

Comment: Ошибка в том, что у чисел по модулю своя арифметика. Реализуйте её в отдельном классе и используйте его экземпляры вместо `double` в матрице системы.

Comment: Откуда я этот метод брал, там написано:Для решения СЛАУ по модулю можно применять описанный выше алгоритм, он сохраняет свою корректность.

Разумеется, теперь становится ненужным использовать какие-то хитрые техники выбора опорного элемента — достаточно найти любой ненулевой элемент в текущем столбце.

Если модуль простой, то никаких сложностей вообще не возникает — происходящие по ходу работы алгоритма Гаусса деления не создают особых проблем.

Comment: Все правильно. Алгоритм корректен. Но у чисел своя арифметика. Для комплексных чисел алгоритм тоже может быть корректен, но если вы будете работать с ними как с типом `double`, то очевидно будет ошибка.

Comment: А как это примерно будет выглядеть, подскажите, пожалуйста, пока что-то не особо представляю. Я добавил еще обычный метод Гаусса, он вроде попроще, но все равно как изменить не представляю

Comment: Это не настолько тривиально, чтобы код как в блокноте писать, а скопировать мне неоткуда. Но вообще говоря может быть будет достаточно перевести только входные и выходные аргументы (здесь могу и ошибаться, т.к. в теории чисел не силен, а под рукой справочника нет).

Comment: Уже несколько дней голову ломаю, никак реализовать не могу

Comment: Или ищите формулы и начинайте реализовывать или ждите пока придет кто-то, кому будет не лень написать/скопировать код за вас. А может быть будет предложено другое, более простое решение.

Comment: Буду надеяться, что люди добрые помогут)